# Which versions of TECO had merged G- and Q-registers?

Tags: history, text, editor

In [this answer to 'Why were TECO variables called Q-registers?'](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12276/7208) I reference [documentation](http://tenex.opost.com/anhc-31-4-anec.pdf) indicating that the original Q-registers were separate from the same-named G-registers. (I.e., `X1` would store text to a different location than `U1` would store a numeric value, and the two separately-stored values could be retrieved with `G1` and `Q1` respectively.)

It appears from [AIM-81](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/5917) that the early PDP-6 versions of TECO had changed this to remove the G-registers completely, storing text or numeric values in same-named Q-registers where writing text would overwrite the numeric value and vice versa. (There were still separate commands for retreiving the text or numeric value, but you had to use the correct one: 'It does not make sense to TECO to "G" a a Q-register given a number by "U" nor to "Q" or "%" a one given text by "X".' (§V p.5))

According to Lars Brinkhoff in the comments on that answer, this combined storage continued to be the case the on PDP-6 versions of TECO and later ITS versions through 1985. Lars also says he has DEC source code with the merged registers. However, [§3.3.2 of the 1985 *Standard TECO* manual](https://github.com/blakemcbride/TECOC/blob/d0a68c3a9e4b9058385626fb106a4ebcb41e100e/doc/teco-manual.txt#L1886) says that 'Each Q-register is divided into two storage areas,' making it pretty clear that these versions for "VAX-11, PDP-11, PDP-10, and PDP-8" (I believe that "PDP-10" here means "TOPS-10") use split storage (though they call all registers 'Q-registers,' regardless of whether you are using X/G or U/Q with them).

So what is the time line and family tree of TECOs that use split versus merged storage for the Q-registers? And is this related in any way to expanding the number of registers that were available?

Please give references to the specific information you used to develop your answer.

Comment: I would suggest emailing Murphy and Samson about how PDP-1 TECO handled registers.  Samson might also know more about the PDP-6 port; his web site is http://gricer.com/

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer.  The ones I know that have Q and G refer to the same register are:

- PDP-6 TECO.  See https://github.com/larsbrinkhoff/its-archives/blob/master/ailab/pdp6-memo-2.pdf and AI memo 81 linked in the question.  There are two versions online, but only in binary form.  Running on an emulator confirms G and Q refer to the same storage.
- ITS TECO.  Version 335 from 1973 online: https://github.com/PDP-10/its-vault/blob/master/files/syseng/teco.335?raw=true (Version 187 from 1971 is preserved but not online.)
- SAIL TECO.  Version "V.001   6 MAY 1967" online: https://saildart.org/TECO%5BCS,SYS%5D
  However, the timestamp is from 1973 so it was probably edited after that.  It seems likely to be Clement's port from PDP-6 TECO, see https://github.com/larsbrinkhoff/its-archives/blob/master/usenet/1990-clements-sail-teco#L28-L33
- TOPS-10 5.03 TECO "V.21A - 18 AUG 70": https://sky-visions.com/dec/tops503/src/teco.21a

In the source files, the code for the G command starts at label `QGET`.  Notice how it calls out to the Q code near `QREG`.  The register storage is at label `QTAB`.

Comment: It's probably worth including in this answer the link in your comment on the question, since it seems to be the earliest evidence we have of the change from split to merged G- and Q-registers.

Comment: So what's the relationship between this stream of TECO development (if it is all one stream) and the "Standard" TECO of the 1985 manual I linked? And in particular, what's the relationship between that TOPS-10 (presumably) version and the TOPS-10 version you mention?

Comment: @cjs, sorry I don't know what the relationship is.  The story goes, Clements updated the MIT TECO to run on the PDP-6 Monitor and this would be the version on which subsequent DEC TECO implementations were modeled.  But this seems inconsistent with the split registers.  I would suggest getting the oldest TECO-8 etc and examine those.

Comment: Presumably Dan Murphy may have brought his PDP-1 TECO to BBN and maybe it spawned some new implementations there which may have moved to DEC.  I encourage you to get in touch with Murphy and others who might remember.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the energy to do a proper research job on this, not to mention I have no background in TECO, ITS, etc. But I am hoping the question will inspire someone better positioned than me to do the research and record their results here.